# How to present a screen-filling CircularProgressIndicator which blocks underlying buttons in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

My goal is that I have a variable in my code which I can simply set to true and than an overlapping Composable will be shown with a small `CircularProgressIndicator` in the middle and a light gray transparant background which blocks input under the view. A lot works, expect for one thing: I am still able to press buttons under the background. This is my code:

```
@Composable
fun ViewWithOverlaysView(mutableState: MutableState<Boolean>) {
    Box {
        Button(onClick = {
            println("Pressed!!")

            mutableState.value = true
        }) {
            Text("XX")
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(Dp(100f)))
        LoadingView(mutableState = mutableState)
    }
}

@Composable
fun LoadingView(mutableState: MutableState<Boolean>) {
    if (mutableState.value) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(
                    Color.LightGray.copy(alpha = 0.5f)
                )
        ) {
            Center {
                CircularProgressIndicator()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now it looks like this, the `XX` button can still be pressed. How can I make sure the user sees a transparant background but is NOT able to press any button beneath the `LoadingView`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `enabled` property of the `Button` composable to control it's clickability:

```kotlin
        Button(
            onClick = {
                println("Pressed!!")
                mutableState.value = true
            },
            enabled = !mutableState.value
        ) {
            Text("XX")
        }
```

Comment: This requires me to add this attributes to EVERY view in my app, this is not do-able. I would assume there is something easier

Answer (score 0):

Adding this modifier to `Box` worked:

```
.clickable(enabled = false) { }
```